# Why is my keras resnet50 model overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, image-processing, keras, residual-networks

I have applied Keras ResNet-50 on a small x-ray image dataset. I tried making layers both trainable and non-trainable, but my model validation accuracy doesn't improve above 50%.

I don't understand how to help my model by solving this overfitting problem. [Here is my Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/mobassir/transfer-learning-siim).